# Css not apply button reside in user contrl from master page

Tags: javascript, jquery

consider a scenario:
i have a master page and master page has .aspx page and .aspx page has some user control.
User control(.ascx) contain buttons 
i want to apply css on a buton which reside in that user control but css are not applied

here is the ContentPlaceHolder in the master page

```
    <div id="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

here is id's of the button on which I am applying css Ok and  btnClose

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
                  $("#Ok").addClass("buttonSmall");
                 $("#btnClose").addClass("buttonSmall");      
             });
```

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: It seams the #Ok element isn't found ... Did you tried lowerCase letters `#ok` instead ?
Could you post the html output ? And why not putting classes in the html source instead of setting it via js ?

Comment: the buttons are reside in user control and i want to apply css directly from master page so i don't have to go through individual page

Comment: There are no. of user control  for every .aspx page so instead of adding classes
to individual button i want to apply it via javascript.
when  i add classes for button reside in .aspx page then it's working fine.
but when it comes to user control not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the resulting HTML (In web browser: right click on page, view source)?

Are the id's of the buttons intact?

If you use the button webcontrol asp.net usually changes the id's of the buttons to be able to keep track of them and their events. Asp.net needs to do this since you might be adding two instances of the same user control to your page and then your button id wouldn't be working.

To access asp.buttons with jquery using their id I've been using the solution here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery